# Loading Url in background in mac command line tool project

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am working on mac command line tool project, and I need to load a url in background using a `WebView`.

**Is it possible to load Url without GUI in Mac OS/X?**

I have went through a few questions before posting here, but no luck.
If it not possible, then is there any other way to achieve this? (In GUI based apps with hiding webview My app doesn't required Window )

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense.  A WebView according to the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) states that WebView is a GUI object that needs to be linked to a window.  By definition you would then need a window, and therefore a GUI to use that component.  What is the final goal you trying to do in the first place with loading this URL?

Comment: @JNYRanger yes I too went to the docs , but my requirement is need to connect to my server(Web socket) by loading url in background without knowing to user, can you please suggest any other way to do this

Comment: Again, not completely sure what you're trying to do loading this URI which could do anything, nor am I up to speed on Cocoa/Obj-C, but it sounds like you should be looking into how to communicate with a server and not loading a webpage (which is what WebView is for) via HTTP requests (or any other web protocol). Good luck!